# Ruby when nil or empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have RoR app, and I want to change some lines of my code to be more elegant.

```
foo = params[:customer][:language].nil? or params[:customer][:language].empty? ? 'es' : params[:customer][:language]
```

I try with

```
foo = params[:customer][:language] || 'es'
```

But it's not the same exactly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `blank?` method?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use activesupport's [`Object#presence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) method, like this:

```
foo = params[:customer][:language].presence || 'es'
```

Comment: `#presence` is very useful. Especially if you have to chain multiple ors like: `city.presence || country.presence || planet.presence`. This line will return first non-nil or non-"" result.